# .Net core Action Filter is being applied to all controllers ignoring decorators

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, action-filter, asp.net-core-3.1

I have defined an `IAsyncActionFilter` (a Microsoft [Action Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#action-filters)) as follows:

```
public class CustomActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{

    public CustomActionFilter()
    {
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I have added its declaration under the `startup` in the `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddScoped<CustomActionFilter>();
```

And at the end of the `ConfigureServices` I configure it as a `Filter`:

```
services.AddMvc((opts) =>
{
    opts.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    opts.Filters.Add(new CustomActionFilter());
});
```

Finally, I use a decorator in a controller, for a specific call, to indicate I want that filter to apply in that call:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("a")]
public class AController : Controller
{

    public AController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet("aa")]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomActionFilter))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoubleA()
    {
        // do something after the filter is called
    }
}
```

So far, everything is working perfectly and the `CustomActionFilter` is being called before and after the `DoubleA` controller is made.

The problem is that **ALL** controllers and routes are using this `CustomActionFilter` regardless of the decorator.

For example in this controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("b")]
public class BController : Controller
{

    public BController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet("bb")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoubleB()
    {
        // do something without any kind of Filter inervention
    }
}
```

The `CustomActionFilter` is being called before and after `DoubleB` as well.

Any ideas what I´m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add a filter to your startup it is applied globally as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution)

If you want it to only apply to your action, removing it from startup should and leaving the attribute on the action should work.

Remove this line from startup should do the trick:

```
opts.Filters.Add(new CustomActionFilter());
```

Comment: Indeed, I didn't read carefully enough the documentation on that part. Thank you!